# How to use pivot in sql server (without aggregates )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

please help me solve this problem: 
You are given a table, containing two columns: 
column is one of the followings:

```
Doctor
Professor
Singer
Actor
```

Write a query to output the names underneath the corresponding occ. in the following format:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+------+

| Doctor | Professor | Singer | Actor|

+--------+-----------+--------+------+
```

Names must be listed in alphabetically sorted order.

Sample Input

```
Name        Occupation
Meera       Singer
Ashely      Professor
Ketty       Professor
Christeen   Professor
Jane        Actor
Jenny       Doctor
Priya       Singer
```

Sample Output

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane

Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia

NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

Note

Print "NULL" when there are no more names corresponding to an occupation.

I tried using :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT [Name], [Occupation] 
FROM occupations 
) AS source
PIVOT
(
    max([Name])
    FOR [occupation] IN ([Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor]) 
) as pvt;
```

which gives the following output:

```
Priya Priyanka Kristeen Samantha
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Why is it that this is required?  As a general principle, using SQL to format data for display purposes is a code-smell.  This structure is not DB friendly and should normally be pushed to a presentation-layer within your application, rather than being completed in the data-layer.  Moving it out of the database helps to ensure that you don't steer your code in to a corner, where you need to develop further SQL on top of this format.  Instead, keep the output from the DB in a relational / normalised form, which is much more adaptable / maintainable / flexible for the future.

Comment: @MatBailie I was thinking the same thing but it is an interview question.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to give each name a row number based on their occupation and order alphabetically.. then include that row number in your pivot query.

```
CREATE TABLE Occupations (
     NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
     Occupation VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
INSERT  INTO Occupations
VALUES
        ('Samantha','Doctor'),
        ('Julia','Actor'),
        ('Maria','Actor'),
        ('Meera','Singer'),
        ('Ashley','Professor'),
        ('Ketty','Professor'),
        ('Christeen','Professor'),
        ('Jane','Actor'),
        ('Jenny','Doctor'),
        ('Priya','Singer');

SELECT
    [Doctor],
    [Professor],
    [Singer],
    [Actor]
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) rn,
         [Name],
         [Occupation] 
     FROM 
         Occupations
    ) AS source 
PIVOT
    (MAX(Name) FOR [occupation] IN ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])) as pvt
ORDER BY rn


DROP TABLE Occupations
```

-- Edit: We need to enclose the subquery after PIVOT within parenthesis "()" to make it work on SQL Server.

Comment: Instead of creating the CTE, you could just list the columns in the select instead of using "select *"

Comment: @JamieD77 Can you please explain need for `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @Rookie_123 pivot basically groups all of your data that is not aggregated.. adding row number gives each name another "grouping" to make them distinct by occupation so the MAX() aggregate does not just one name per occupation, but instead gets one name per Occupation, Row_number.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this in **Oracle**, seemed easier to comprehend:

```
SELECT min(Doctor), min(Professor), min(Singer), min(Actor)
FROM
( Select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation order by Name) rn, 
CASE 
WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' then Name
end as Doctor,
CASE 
WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' then Name
end as Professor,
CASE 
WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' then Name
end as Singer,
CASE 
WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' then Name
end as Actor
from OCCUPATIONS
order by Name) a
group by rn
order by rn;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [Doctor], [Professor], [Singer], [Actor] FROM   
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) ROW_NO, 
    ISNULL(NULL,Name) as Name, Occupation
    FROM Occupations
) AS t 
PIVOT(
    MAX(Name)
    FOR Occupation IN (
        [Doctor], 
        [Professor], 
        [Singer], 
        [Actor]
    )
) AS pivot_table
ORDER BY ROW_NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the MYSQL version of the answer.  Little difficult because of no presence of FULL OUTER JOIN in HACKERRANK.com

```
SET @r1=0, @r2 = 0, @r3 = 0, @r4 = 0;

SELECT t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name
FROM

(SELECT 
    (@r1:=@r1 + 1) AS num1, 
    Name
FROM
    Occupations
    WHERE Occupation = 'Doctor'
ORDER BY Name) as t1

RIGHT JOIN

(SELECT 
    (@r2:=@r2 + 1) AS num2, 
    Name
FROM
    Occupations
    WHERE Occupation = 'Professor'
ORDER BY Name) as t2

ON t1.num1 = t2.num2

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    (@r3:=@r3 + 1) AS num3, 
    Name
FROM
    Occupations
    WHERE Occupation = 'Singer'
ORDER BY Name) as t3

ON t2.num2 = t3.num3

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
    (@r4:=@r4 + 1) AS num4, 
    Name
FROM
    Occupations
    WHERE Occupation = 'Actor'
ORDER BY Name) as t4

ON t2.num2 = t4.num4
```

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL ANSWER WITH EXPLANATION

```
select
Doctor,
Professor,
Singer,
Actor
 from (
select
    NameOrder,
    max(case Occupation when 'Doctor' then Name end) as Doctor,
    max(case Occupation when 'Professor' then Name end) as Professor,
    max(case Occupation when 'Singer' then Name end) as Singer,
    max(case Occupation when 'Actor' then Name end) as Actor
from (
        select
            Occupation,
            Name,
            row_number() over(partition by Occupation order by Name ASC) as NameOrder
        from Occupations
     ) as NameLists
group by NameOrder
) as Names
```

Selects the names of people with four different occupations (Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor) from a table called "Occupations". The table has two columns, "Name" and "Occupation", which contain the names of people and their occupations, respectively.

The query uses a series of nested SQL statements to accomplish this. Here is a breakdown of each part of the query:

1. The outermost SELECT statement lists the four occupations as columns that will be returned in the result set: Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor.
2. The FROM clause contains a subquery that selects the names of people with each occupation and arranges them into columns based on the order of their names. This is done using the ROW_NUMBER() function, which assigns a unique number to each row within a partition of the data (in this case, the partition is by occupation). This number is used to order the names within each occupation group.
3. The subquery in the FROM clause uses the MAX() function with a CASE statement to pivot the rows of data into columns. This creates a result set where each row represents a unique name order and the columns contain the names of people with each occupation. The MAX() function is used to select only the highest ranked name within each occupation group, which is determined by the NameOrder value.
4. The outermost query groups the results by the NameOrder column, which effectively removes the duplicate rows that were created by the inner subquery. The resulting rows contain the names of people with each occupation in the correct order.

Answer (score -3):

```
SET @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3 =0, @r4=0;
SELECT MIN(Doctor), MIN(Professor), MIN(Singer), MIN(Actor) FROM
(SELECT CASE Occupation WHEN 'Doctor' THEN @r1:=@r1+1
                       WHEN 'Professor' THEN @r2:=@r2+1
                       WHEN 'Singer' THEN @r3:=@r3+1
                       WHEN 'Actor' THEN @r4:=@r4+1 END
       AS RowLine,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END AS Doctor,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Professor' THEN Name END AS Professor,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Singer' THEN Name END AS Singer,
       CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Actor' THEN Name END AS Actor
       FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY Name) AS t
GROUP BY RowLine;
```

Comment: You got that from here: https://nifannn.github.io/2017/10/21/SQL-Notes-Hackerrank-Occupations/ ... Remember to link to the source!!

Comment: @mahesh Dont just copy and paste. Explain the code too