# How to display all data with nulls using Pivot

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot, pivot-table

I'm currently trying the pivot function of oracle pl sql but I cant seem to display my desired output,

I need to Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

Note: I should print NULL when there are no more names corresponding to an occupation.

using this table definition

```
 create table occupations
(
     name varchar2(100),
     occupation varchar2(100)
); 
insert into occupations
values ('Samantha', 'Doctor');
insert into occupations
values ('Jenny', 'Doctor');
insert into occupations
values ('Julia', 'Actor');
insert into occupations
values ('Maria', 'Actor');
insert into occupations
values ('Jane', 'Actor');
insert into occupations
values ('Meera', 'Singer');
insert into occupations
values ('Priya', 'Singer');
insert into occupations
values ('Ashely', 'Professor');
insert into occupations
values ('Ketty', 'Professor');
insert into occupations
values ('Christeen', 'Professor');
```

and I want an output like this one using pivot function

```
Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
```

The first column is an alphabetically ordered list of Doctor names.

The second column is an alphabetically ordered list of Professor names.

The third column is an alphabetically ordered list of Singer names.

The fourth column is an alphabetically ordered list of Actor names.

The empty cell data for columns with less than the maximum number of names per occupation (in this case, the Professor and Actor columns) are filled with NULL values.

So far, my current query is this,

```
select * from
(
    select name, occupation
      from occupations
)
pivot
(  
    min(name) 
    for occupation  in ('Doctor','Professor','Singer','Actor')
)
```

But I only get one row.

> Jenny Ashely  Meera   Jane

any tips and explantion? thanks.

Comment: I know this is a hackerrank problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem. There is already a solution here for sql-server, same works for oracle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017430/how-to-use-pivot-in-sql-server-without-aggregates

Comment: the mentioned answer for sql-server re-arranged here (for oracle) 
 : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/39f506/16

Comment: i see. thanks @KaushikNayak

Comment: thanks @BarbarosÖzhan i already modify the answer for oracle. but big thanks anyways